# Imaging an iso in a certain partion of usb-drive to make it bootable and Windows-compatible storage

Tags: partition, live-usb

I have a usb-drive which I want to use both as storage (for windows too) and as a (Linux) Bootable. So I have to image the ISO of the linux distribution that I have into a specific partition of my usb drive. Suppose the drive is `sdc` and I have made two partitions: `sdc1` for storage(NTFS) in the beginning and `sdc2` (FAT32) following that (I use GParted).

I know that for the simple case of just making the drive bootable we use `dd` as :

```
    dd if=name.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=512k
```

That would of course image the iso in the drive, not the specific partition,making it impossible to use the usb as storage. I thought of using `/dev/sdc2` as the destination instead of `/dev/sdc` but after googling I concluded that's not how it's supposed to work. So why can't I just use `/dev/sdc2` ? I tried both:

Writing to `/dev/sdc` changes any partitions I have made and it creates 2 partitions  in the beginning and leaves the rest unallocated, as it's supposed to.Writing to `/dev/sdc2`  doesn't "mess" with the partitions I have and it just writes in the second partition.

So what do I have to do? Do I have to partition the drive in another way (I've read this [How do I partition a USB drive so that it's bootable and has a Windows-compatible data storage partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30322/how-do-i-partition-a-usb-drive-so-that-its-bootable-and-has-a-windows-compatibl)) ?

Having done the partition correctly, how must I use `dd` to write in a specific partition?

Answer (score 2):

`dd`-ing the ISO to a partition doesn't work because the ISO itself contains a partition table, as you discovered. But what you can do is create your partitions after the fact.

1. `dd` the ISO to the entire USB disk (ex. sdc)
2. Add any additional partitions using a partitioning tool.

You mentioned the ISO creates two partitions, so that means you can create at most two additional *primary* partitions.

Comment: If I `dd` the iso first, then it creates the two partitions in the beginning. Windows only sees the first partition on a drive.Can I move these to the end and then add another primary partition in the beginning?

Comment: Oh, Windows, why must you be so difficult! Hmm... With the ISO dd'd and the drive connected to your PC, do you see any symlinks in /dev/disk/by-* pointing to the two partitions? My first thought was no, that the bootloader is expecting the partitions to be as they are. But, perhaps it's using either a partition or filesystem label to detect them. If the latter is the case, then the partition order won't matter.